# Как проверить были ли все кликнуты элементы?

Tags: c#, winforms

**есть picturebox и на нем по координатам расположены выделенные объекты,как проверить что все элементы были кликнуты?
вот часть кода:**

```
public Form4()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        objects = new List<MapObject2>();
        objects.Add(new MapObject2()
        {
            Name = "Мумия",
            X = 258,
            Y = 136,
            Width = 24,
            Height = 43
        });

        objects.Add(new MapObject2()
        {
            Name = "Банка",
            X = 286,
            Y = 178,
            Width = 17,
            Height = 17
        });

        objects.Add(new MapObject2()
        {
            Name = "Змеи",
            X = 370,
            Y = 303,
            Width = 23,
            Height = 19
        });

        objects.Add(new MapObject2()
        {
            Name = "Царь",
            X = 73,
            Y = 132,
            Width = 31,
            Height = 42
        });

        objects.Add(new MapObject2()
        {
            Name = "Колесница",
            X = 352,
            Y = 103,
            Width = 65,
            Height = 41
        });

        objects.Add(new MapObject2()
        {
            Name = "Конь",
            X = 5,
            Y = 163,
            Width = 15,
            Height = 38
        });

    }
    List<MapObject2> objects;
private void PictureBox2_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int currentX = e.X;
        int currentY = e.Y;
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++)
        {
            if (currentX > (objects[i].X - objects[i].Width / 2) & currentX < (objects[i].X + objects[i].Width / 2)
            & currentY > (objects[i].Y - objects[i].Height / 2) & currentY < (objects[i].Y + objects[i].Height / 2))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ты нашел слово!");

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Ответ добавил. Кстати у вас как-то странно определяется положение объекта:

 `if (currentX > (objects[i].X - objects[i].Width / 2) & currentX < (objects[i].X + objects[i].Width / 2)
& currentY > (objects[i].Y - objects[i].Height / 2) & currentY < (objects[i].Y + objects[i].Height / 2))` 

это так и задумано напополам их обрезать? или x, y - это центр?

Comment: все верно)это центр)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно решить задачу "в лоб" (не идеально) я бы предложил создать в классе MapObject2 свойство или поле IsClicked в котором отмечалось бы прокликан этот объект или нет.

Код для класса MapObject2

```
public   class MapObject2
{
    public string Name;
    public int X;

    public int Y;
    public int Width;
    public int Height;

    public bool IsClicked = false;
}
```

Часть кода формы (я кстати координаты ваши подвинул - удобнее чтоб было для примера в рядок их расположить):

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int currentX = e.X;
        int currentY = e.Y;
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++)
        {
            if (currentX > (objects[i].X - objects[i].Width / 2) & currentX < (objects[i].X + objects[i].Width / 2)
            & currentY > (objects[i].Y - objects[i].Height / 2) & currentY < (objects[i].Y + objects[i].Height / 2))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ты нашел слово: " + objects[i].Name);
                //Отмечаем что данный объект прокликан
                objects[i].IsClicked = true;
            }
        }

        //Проверяем все ли объекты прокликаны
        if (IsAllClicked()) MessageBox.Show("Все объекты прокликаны");
    }

    //Проверка коллекции объектов - все ли прокликаны
    private bool IsAllClicked()
    {
        bool AllObjectsClicked = true;
        foreach (MapObject2 item in objects)
        {
            if (!item.IsClicked)
            {
                AllObjectsClicked = false; break;
            }
        }
        return AllObjectsClicked;
    }

    //Необязательная часть - просто чтобы ориентироваться в "пространстве"
    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       label1.Text = e.X.ToString();


        int find = -1;
        int currentX = e.X;
        int currentY = e.Y;
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++)
        {
            if (currentX > (objects[i].X - objects[i].Width / 2) & currentX < (objects[i].X + objects[i].Width / 2)
            & currentY > (objects[i].Y - objects[i].Height / 2) & currentY < (objects[i].Y + objects[i].Height / 2))
            {
                find = i;
            }
        }
        if (find >= 0) label2.Text = objects[find].Name;
        else label2.Text = "---";

    }
```

Не забудьте создать в вашей форме label1 и label2 - если будете пользоваться обработчиком pictureBox1_MouseMove. [image: Вот что примерно у меня получилось]

[На всякий случай - проект на github](https://github.com/lvovandrey/StackoverflowQuestion.git)

Я не знаю как у вас строится объект MapObject2, но я строю игровые единицы (когда извращаюсь на WPF) примерно как Unity: [статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/270825/) Это конечно ООП головного мозга. Но все же.

Comment: спасибо огромное!